# Tool for displaying binary decision tree

Tags: .net, xml, binary-tree, data-visualization

The system I'm currently working on involves the creation of binary decision trees. Lots of them. Some of them are stored in XML format so they can be analyzed manually if needed.

The tree structure is basically nested <NODE> tags. Each node may also have a few child tags defining the properties of the node.

What I would like to do is display the trees graphically. Vertically or horizontally does not matter but I would like to use a geometrically tree-shaped layout e.g. like this:

[image]

...rather than the layout commonly used in file system browsers, which isn't the best way to display binary trees.

Is there a .NET based library or, alternatively, a stand-alone tool which does this well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) ? There are some language bindings for .Net (see [resources](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php)), and it can output in a variety of formats (so you can view using SVG/HTML/Flex, standalone viewers etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I have glimpsed it but it seems to use a proprietary input language rather than XML? I'll check it out more thoroughly.

Comment: It is their custom text format, but very easy to generate, especially with a library. I'd rather not call it 'proprietary', it is well-documented and open.

Comment: Agreed. It's not XML, but it is well-established and commonly used

Comment: Thanks again. I have looked at the .NET resources using Graphviz for visualization. It's clearly doable, albeit with a bit more indirection than I was hoping for. I'll leave the question open a little while longer...

Comment: +1, although it can be more difficult to arrange graphviz in a left/right order.

Answer (score 2):

**graphViz**

The selected answer also recommends *graphviz* but doesn't provide an rendered example; what's more the comments below that answer mention that *graphviz* is not easy to use for the purpose recited in the question.

i disagree. I actually use *graphviz* for this purpose--as a library (via *python* bindings supplied by *pygraphviz*) for plotting the output (i.e., the structure created by running the [C4.5 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) against a training set). Setting the graph type as a directed graph (*digraph* is the formal syntax), graphviz' SMACOF algorithm gives you a nice tree structure right out of the box.

For instance:

[alt text http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/9290/btreeingraphviz.png](http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/9290/btreeingraphviz.png)

To create the graph below, i kept the default values for all of the 'graph' parameters that affect layout (e.g., nodesep, ranksep, ratio), with the exception of 'orientation', which i set to 'landscape' (default is 'portraint').

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a WPF based package on CodeProject:

[A Graph Tree Drawing Control for WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/LayeredTreeDraw.aspx)

Looks simplistic enough and should cover my needs. Any comments on this?